# custom recognizer in bot composer

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

Can I know how to use custom recognizer in bot composer. As per MS document it is mentioned that Custom recognizer: enables you to customize your own recognizer by editing JSON in the form. But how to create it is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

By 'Editing the JSON in the form' Microsoft means that you can specify the `$kind` of the recognizer that you use. You'll then need to write a custom recognizer that implements `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Recognizer` and register it with the bots dependency injection framework via a customer Nuget package.

So for example you write some C# code for the class

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs

public class MySpecialRecognizer : Recognizer {
    public const string Kind = "MyNamespace.MySpecialRecognizer";
    public virtual Task<RecognizerResult> RecognizeAsync(DialogContext dialogContext, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default, Dictionary<string, string> telemetryProperties = null, Dictionary<string, double> telemetryMetrics = null) {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Write your code here");
    }
}
```

You can then follow the steps at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-create-packages to create a package and register the type
`services.AddSingleton<DeclarativeType>(sp => new DeclarativeType<MySpecialRecognizer>(MySpecialRecognizer.Kind));`

Add this NuGet package to your bot, and finally, in the bot composer change the recognizer type to Custom and in the box that pops up, specify the $kind of your custom recognizer

```
{
    "$kind": "MyNamespace.MySpecialRecognizer"
}
```

You can also add other properties in the JSON that will be picked up and serialized into your custom recognizer if you need to specify keys or other bot-specific variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples of custom recognizers:

1. [CustomQuestionAnswering](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-components/tree/main/packages/Recognizers/CustomQuestionAnswering)
2. [ConversationLanguageUnderstanding](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-components/tree/main/packages/Recognizers/ConversationLanguageUnderstanding/dotnet)

These two packages are intended to help you add custom recognizer to an empty bot built with Composer.

[Documentation link](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-components/tree/main/packages/Recognizers/CustomQuestionAnswering/dotnet#configuration) to configure the recognizer in Composer dialog.